# Any other names for what you are operating on (eg. Radicand)?

Tags: terminology

I had heard of the term radicand to describe the part under a square root. Recently I heard the term integrand to describe the part being integrated.

I was wondering if there were any other terms like this?

Comment: minuend${{{}}}$?

Comment: Summand, of course.

Comment: There is also "operand". From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operand): *"In mathematics an operand is the object of a mathematical operation, i.e. it is the object or quantity that is operated on."*

Comment: I suppose this is where we get the term dividend from? Bit strange that this ends in ‘end’ instead of the usual ‘and’.

Comment: Incidentally, is there a term for the function you are taking a limit of? I haven't heard something like "limitand" being used.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth I think the term *operand* covers all cases. There's no need to multiply terms that are isomorphic mod being the argument of an operation when we can call them all operand, in general.